# Unresolved symbols NewShortArray and SetShortArrayRegion

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to use short[] and jshortArray between C/JAVA as follows in Eclipse:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_testingForFun_testFunc
          (JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jshort num, jshortArray data) {
    jshort outCArray[] = {100, 200};
    jshortArray outJNIArray = (*env)->NewShortArray(env, 2);  // allocate
    if (NULL == outJNIArray) return;
    (*env)->SetShortArrayRegion(env, outJNIArray, 0 , 2, outCArray);  // copy
    //return outJNIArray;
}
```

I've created the header file using javah and included it. However, Eclipse says NewShortArray and  SetShortArrayRegion are unresolved and I can't build the apk. However, not using arrays (jshort and short) works fine. I looked in jni.h and it seems that NewShortArray other related functions are defined if __cplusplus is defined, but I'm using C. I also built the apk on the command line using ndk-build and ant and I read outJNIArray[0] or [1] = 0 in the calling function, so it's not working there either. How do I resolve this issue?

Additionally, Eclipse can't resolve ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG in:

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "FibLib.c", "fibNI(%lld)", n);
```

even though

```
#include <android/log.h>
```

is at the beginning of the file.

Comment: You need to add `LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid` to your `Android.mk`.

Comment: Based on your edit, it sounds like your `sysroot` is not correct. Or your header and lib paths are not correct. Please show us something, like your `Android.mk` or the output of the compiler invocation.

Answer (score 0):

I used Eclipse restart and seems to have cleared up these issues. But every time I edit my .c file, the unresolved errors pop up, and I need to restart. It's very annoying. Any fix for this?

The issue of outJNIArray[] not being set is a separate topic, so I will ask another question on the forum in the future if necessary.

Comment: *"...issue of outJNIArray[] not being set "* - you need to call `GetShortArrayElements` to get a pointer to the array. You need to write the modified array back with `ReleaseShortArrayElements` and the `0` flag. That's assuming you're doing basic array operations like modifying values, and not doing special memory management with it.

Comment: Actually every time I edit my .c file, the unresolved errors pop up. It seems that all I need to do is restart Eclipse (no need for clean), but it's very annoying. Any fix for this?

Comment: @jww: I use (*env)->SetShortArrayRegion(env, outJNIArray, 0 , 2, outCArray);  to set the values to [100, 200], but I read back 0 in the app.

Comment: @jww: I understand what you're saying now. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @jww: If my C-function's parameter list returns a pointer to shorts and the number of shorts pointed to, then how would I pre-allocate the java short[] with the correct size in the calling class?